# Magento 2: no search results

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.2.8

When I enter a search query, Magento returns "no results". I am not using any search-related extensions. Already tried reindexing.

Where should I start debugging this?

I am running Magento 2.2.8

Comment: By what keyword you are trying to search?

Comment: regular strings, for example "shirt"

Comment: This issue comes till the time of set up OR just after a few customizations?

Comment: I am not completely sure. It did work fine, I think it stopped working after upgrading to 2.2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem, apparently there was a problem with the indexer, which failed on duplicated entries on `catalog_product_index_eav_temp`:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3196-193-1-170-3196' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

To fix it I had to manually update +- 100 records in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table. For example: update value=170,170 to value=170

Answer (score 1):

Please check in admin product attributes set as searchable.

eg:

1. Store >> Attributes >> Product
2. Search for Name
3. Check Storefront Properties >> Use in Search set as YES

Comment: checked this, attributes were already set op searchable